# Reset values when select changes using javascript on form

Tags: javascript, forms, select, reset

I am currently displaying either KG or Stone fields to the user, if the user selects A it hides B and viceversa. The problem is if the user fills KG out and switches to stone it will send both values.

The problem is resetting the value of B when A is selected.

I've tried for example setting the ID of the textfield of B to reset within the switch javascript so when one value is set reset the other value using:

```
document.getElementById("reset").defaultValue;
```

Along with a lot of other things I've found from other questions but with no success. Anyone can point me in the right direction?

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    toggleFields(); 
    $("#dbType").change(function () {
        toggleFields();
    });

});
function toggleFields() {
    if ($("#dbType").val() === "stone"){
        $("#stone").show();
         $("#kg").hide();
}
    else if ($("#dbType").val() === "kg"){
        $("#kg").show();
        $("#stone").hide();
    }
}
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="stone">    
 <input class="inputfield" type="text" id="reset" name="stone" />

 <input class="inputfield" type="text" id="reset" name="pounds" />
    </div>

    <div id="kg">
   <input class="inputfield" type="text" name="kg"/>
    </div>
```

Comment: Is this on the right course? `else if ($("#dbType").val() === "kg"){
        $("#kg").show();
        $("#stone").hide();
  document.getElementById("reset").defaultValue;
 }`

Comment: can you please create a working copy using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/). The problem is not clear from code

Comment: @brk https://jsfiddle.net/whwtf2jq/

Answer (score 0):

Just do the reset in the `toggleFields` method you already have:

```
function toggleFields() {
    if ($("#dbType").val() === "stone"){
        $("#stone").show();
         $("#kg").hide();
         //then reset it too
         $('input[name="kg"]').val("");
}
    else if ($("#dbType").val() === "kg"){
        $("#kg").show();
        $("#stone").hide();
         //then reset it too
         $('input[name="stone"]').val("");
    }
}
```

change `.val("")` to whatever you want to reset it to.

Comment: DOH! so simple yet I've spent over an hour trying to figure it out! Thanks alot for your help!